# GTA 5 is not using my external gpu. Is there anyway to fix it?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I already tried to add the game from nvida control panel. Tried to add commandline.txt method. i have asus laptop gtx 1050ti and i5 7300hq.

Comment: So your monitor is utilizing a different piece of hardware depending on what program you're currently running?

Comment: hmm. when you put it like that it sounds weird but yeah. its a optimus laptop and for some reoson it is not utilazing my external gpu

Comment: It's for that reason I don't think this is a GTA 5 issue, I think it's a hardware / software issue. I think you'd have a better chance of finding an answer in the GPU forums that are game specific. Also double check that you don't have any other programs running that could be interfering with video out streams.

Comment: okay thanks for advice. i will see whhat i can do. thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome and good luck.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to the GPU you have if it's an eGPU?